# Slide elements on View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to add some kind of effect to my application. I would like to slide left/right to the View Controller, element by element. Something like in PowerPoint presentation. Is there an easy way to do it? I am developing iPhone app.

Comment: take a `UIScrollView` and use paging mode: [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you need to use a `UIScrollView` with some [paging](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/). Check the official [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH3-SW1%5D) about this.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I guess that I could use  setContentOffset:animated: to scroll to specific location. Thanks!